# Vinogradov's Theorem Estimates-$ e\Big(\frac{-Na}{q}\Big)\int_{-\frac{1}{Q}}^{\frac{1}{Q}}O\Big(N^3 ..= O\Big(N^2 \operatorname{exp}(-c_2\sqrt)) $

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

In Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory, I am reading the proof of Vinogradov's Theorem and it is estimating the sum

$$S(\alpha)=\sum_{\substack{k \leq N \\ (k,q)=1}}\Lambda(k) e(k \alpha)$$

Then it computes $$S(\alpha)^3$$ and uses this to get an estimate for

$$r(N)=\int_{0}^{1}S(\alpha)^3 e(-N\alpha) d\alpha$$

In the step, I am stuck in the following. I would appreciate if anyone can explain this step

$$    r(N) = \int_{0}^{1}S(\alpha)^3 e(-N\alpha) d\alpha $$
$$ = e\Big(\frac{-Na}{q}\Big)\int_{-\frac{1}{Q}}^{\frac{1}{Q}}S(\alpha)^3 e(-N\beta) d\beta $$
$$= e\Big(\frac{-Na}{q}\Big)\int_{-\frac{1}{Q}}^{\frac{1}{Q}}\Big(\frac{\mu(q)}{\phi(q)^3}T(\beta)^3+O\Big(N^3 \operatorname{exp}(-c_1\sqrt{\log N})\Big)\Big) d\beta $$
$$ \frac{\mu(q)}{\phi(q)^3} e\Big(\frac{-Na}{q}\Big)\int_{-\frac{1}{Q}}^{\frac{1}{Q}}T(\beta)^3 d\beta    +   
  e\Big(\frac{-Na}{q}\Big)\int_{-\frac{1}{Q}}^{\frac{1}{Q}}O\Big(N^3 \operatorname{exp}(-c_2\sqrt{\log N})\Big) d\beta $$
$$ \frac{\mu(q)}{\phi(q)^3} e\Big(\frac{-Na}{q}\Big)\int_{-\frac{1}{Q}}^{\frac{1}{Q}}T(\beta)^3 d\beta    +   
  O\Big(N^2 \operatorname{exp}(-c_2\sqrt{\log N})\Big)
$$

I cannot understand how $$  e\Big(\frac{-Na}{q}\Big)\int_{-\frac{1}{Q}}^{\frac{1}{Q}}O\Big(N^3 \operatorname{exp}(-c_1\sqrt{\log N})\Big) d\beta= O\Big(N^2 \operatorname{exp}(-c_2\sqrt{\log N})\Big)
$$

Here are my thoughts, $e\Big(\frac{-Na}{q}\Big)$ has modulus $1$, so it is none of our concern. Secondly considering the integrand, we have
$$N^3 \operatorname{exp}(-c_1\sqrt{\log N}) \ll N^3 \operatorname{exp}(-c_3\sqrt{\log N})$$ for some $c_3$ and hence, we have an upperbound on the integrand for sufficently large $N$. And thus this integral is bounded by $$\frac{2}{Q}N^3 \operatorname{exp}(-c_3\sqrt{\log N})=\frac{2(\log N)^B}{1}N^2 \operatorname{exp}(-c_3\sqrt{\log N}) \ll O\Big(N^2 \operatorname{exp}(-c_2\sqrt{\log N})\Big)$$ for some $c_2$, we have the desired estimates. Is this correct?

Comment: Your understanding has no problems